# Executing a remote MySQL query over SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, bash

I am trying to execute a `MySQL` query over `ssh` using the following command:

```
ssh -p 2020 mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com "mysql --verbose --compress --secure-auth --database ops --execute \
'INSERT INTO \`ops\`.\`accounts\` (\`alias\`, \`id\`, \`web_server\`, \`mysql_server\`) VALUES ('foobar', 'foobar', 'web2', 'mysql1')'"
```

The problem is that when this is executed, the single quotes around `foobar`, `foobar`, `web2`, and `mysql1` are removed. Here is the error response from MySQL:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'foobar' in 'field list'
--------------
INSERT INTO `ops`.`accounts` (`alias`, `id`, `web_server`, `mysql_server`) VALUES (foobar, foobar, web2, mysql1)
--------------
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was added another layer of escaped single quotes around the values.

```
ssh -p 2020 mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com "mysql --verbose --compress --secure-auth --database ops --execute \
'INSERT INTO \`ops\`.\`accounts\` (\`alias\`, \`id\`, \`web_server\`, \`mysql_server\`) VALUES ('\'foobar\'', '\'foobar\'', '\'web2\'', '\'mysql1\'')'"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```sh
echo "INSERT INTO `ops`.`accounts` (`alias`, `id`, `web_server`, `mysql_server`) VALUES ('foobar', 'foobar', 'web2', 'mysql1')" | ssh mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com "mysql --verbose --compress --secure-auth --database ops"
```

You can also forward a local port to your remote server:

```sh
$ ssh -L2206:localhost:3306 mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com
```

Then, in another terminal, you will be able to connect your remote MySQL server using the `mysql` command:

```sh
$ mysql --host localhost --port 2206
```